# How to hide simulation variables in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

Is it possible to hide objects or outputs after I have simulated a model? I have a ton of objects and I feel like I am wasting time sifting through them trying to find my correct response.

If not, is there a way to organize the way my outputs are displayed in the simulation tab?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this blog entry: http://www.claytex.com/blog/selection-of-variables-to-be-saved-in-the-result-file/

Answer (score 4):

The main possibilities in Dymola are:

- Make components protected. As default protected components are not included in the results.
- Use the selection of variables as linked by @Lukas-Exel http://www.claytex.com/blog/selection-of-variables-to-be-saved-in-the-result-file/ In Dymola 2017 FD01 there is also a GUI for this Edit>Variable Selections
- Filter which variables are shown from the result - text-field under the Variable Browser (before Dymola 2017 FD01 that is found under "More").

You can also combine these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Optionally, there can be used `HideResult` in the variable annotation (but don't overuse it!):

```
Real myVar annotation(HideResult = true);
```